# AWS cloudformatiom template

Tags: amazon-web-services

is this possible to List of unused and empty s3 buckets in Excel sheet using CloudFormation template
list unused and empty s3 buckets  in excel sheet using Cloudformation template

template will create a lambda function which will list unused and empty s3 buckets and print that list in a excel form

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: CloudFormation does not support 'logic/compute' operations. However, CloudFormation can launch resources that can perform compute logic, such as EC2 instances or AWS Lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. You can program any logic you want with [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudForamtion.